# jQuery - I want to select a row and alert it

Tags: jquery

I want to select a row and get username to alert box.. So I use jquery selectors to do this task. But Unfortunately jquery gives first rows data always. What is the solution for it?

Here my html data

```
<tabel>

<?php
while(!result){
?>
<tr>
<td><input type='hidden' name='edit' value = <?php $result['username'] ?> /> <button id='edit' value='edit' >Edit User</button>'<td>

</tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

### jquery

```
var cmd = $('input[name=edit]').val();
alert('cmd');


What is the solution for it?
```

Comment: You want to alert the `username` when a user 'select' it. You mean when a user 'click' on the row or input?

Comment: yes it is. Click on the edit button

Comment: Your code has some issues (e.g. `<?php $result['username'] ?>` should be `<?php echo $result['username']; ?>` and would be more helpful for help if more complete.

Comment: You probably want to change `names` and `ids` to more unique values.

Comment: or even use classes.

Comment: when do you select the value? on click of edit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the `id="edit"` of your button to a `class="edit"` since id should be used uniquely.
Sample html

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type='hidden' name='edit' value ='1' /> 
        <button class='edit' value='edit' >Edit User</button>
    </td>
</tr>    
    <tr>
    <td><input type='hidden' name='edit' value ='2' /> 
        <button class='edit' value='edit' >Edit User</button>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type='hidden' name='edit' value ='3' /> 
        <button class='edit' value='edit' >Edit User</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

//**using prev() function**
Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$('.edit').live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).prev('input').val());
})
```

//**`Or using parent() and find() function`**

read about [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector

read about [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) selector

```
  $('.edit').live('click',function(){
        alert($(this).parent().find('input').val());
    })
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/07eqekx0/)

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this. I have formatted your code a little bit since its having some issues.

**HTML/PHP**

```
<table>
<?php
    while(!$result){
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' name='edit' value = '<?php echo $result["username"]; ?>' />
            <button id='edit' value='edit'>Edit User</button>
        <td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        var cmd = $(this).prev('input').val();
        alert(cmd);
    });
</script>
```